# How to add on dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry for the vague question, I really don't know what to make of this.

This is my code:

```
area="""AREA,POPULATION,CHILD
ARKANSAS,2000,20
TEXAS,50,5"""
def createFiles():
    x = open('area.txt','w')
    x.write(area)
    x.close()
createFiles()


city = {}
total = 0
with open('area.txt', 'r') as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        data = line.strip().split(',')
        place = data[0]
        city[place] = {}
        city[place]['Population'] = int(data[1])
        city[place]['Children'] = int(data[2])
print(city)
choose=input('Choose area ARKANSAS/TEXAS: ')
addPopu=input('Add population: ')
addChild=input('Add Children: ')
```

For reasons, the variable "area" is going to be a txt file named "area.txt"

for example I choose area TEXAS, TEXAS has 50 Population and 5 Children.

I add 10 in Population and 5 on Children so it's value will change to 60 Population and 10 children, How do I do this?

my Output should look like this:

```
{'ARKANSAS': {'Population': 2000, 'Children': 20}, 'TEXAS': {'Population': 50, 'Children': 5}}
Choose area ARKANSAS/TEXAS: TEXAS
Add population: 10
Add Children: 5
{'ARKANSAS': {'Population': 2000, 'Children': 20}, 'TEXAS': {'Population': 60, 'Children': 10}}
```

Comment: ```
a = {"test": 1};
a["test"] += 1
```

Comment: Before getting to the core of the question as you’ve posed it, you really should consider using a pre-built CSV parser/writer to read this data instead of rolling your own. There are quite a few edge cases that you would need to account for to make your own fully spec-compliant that these pre-built libraries already take into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

This should do that

```
 # add the input population and children to the chosen area
city[choose]['Population'] += int(addPopu)
city[choose]['Children'] += int(addChild)

# rewriting the area.txt file with updated values
with open('area.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("AREA,POPULATION,CHILD\n")
    for place in city:
        file.write(f"{place},{city[place]['Population']},{city[place]['Children']}\n")

print(city)
```